# Convert polygon to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, polygon, subtraction, r-sp

I have created a polygon by substracting two polygons, derived from large dataframes. More specific:

```
plot(Cyp_occ_4326_df$lon, Cyp_occ_4326_df$lat,
     xlim=c(min(Cyp_csl_4326_df$lon),max(Cyp_csl_4326_df$lon)),
     ylim=c(min(Cyp_csl_4326_df$lat),max(Cyp_csl_4326_df$lat)), 
     type='p', col='red', xlab='x', ylab='y')
points(Cyp_csl_4326_df$lon, Cyp_csl_4326_df$lat, col='blue')
```

[image]

where Cyp_csl_4326_df is a dataframe (blue points) and  Cyp_occ_4326_df
is another dataframe (red points), which overlays with the first dataframe at the upper part.

I have created a polygon by substracting the two dataframes as follow:

```
poly1 <- Polygon(as.matrix(Cyp_csl_4326_df))
poly2 <- Polygon(as.matrix(Cyp_occ_4326_df))
p1 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(poly1), "p1")))
p2 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(poly2), "p2")))
res <- gDifference(p1, p2)
```

And I got the following pic:

plot(res, col="blue")

[image]

The problem is that I do not know how to convert the derived polygon to points for further use. What I get, is simply the extend of the polygon:

```
> summary(res)
Object of class SpatialPolygons
Coordinates:
       min      max
x 32.27102 34.58771
y 34.56312 35.69493
Is projected: NA 
proj4string : [NA]
```

I could not find a way to extract points.

Answer (score 1):

I base my answer on data from the `sf` package for replication:

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# Convert data to the same class as yours
library(sp)
res <- as_Spatial(nc$geometry)
summary(res)
```

```
Object of class SpatialPolygons
Coordinates:
        min       max
x -84.32385 -75.45698
y  33.88199  36.58965
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string : [+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs]
```

With this example data the following code seems to work:

```
# Load data.table for the rbindlist() function
library(data.table)

# Extract points from SpatialPolygons
res_points <- lapply(1:length(res@polygons), function(i) {
  
  lapply(1:length(res@polygons[[i]]@Polygons), function(j){
        
    data.frame(res@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[j]]@coords)
    
  }) %>% rbindlist()
  
}) %>% rbindlist()

head(res_points)
```

```
          X1       X2
1: -81.47276 36.23436
2: -81.54084 36.27251
3: -81.56198 36.27359
4: -81.63306 36.34069
5: -81.74107 36.39178
6: -81.69828 36.47178
```

Comment: Dear @L-- Thanks for your solution, it works!
Is it possible though to remove the thin black lines at the upper part (above the blue area of the polygon)?
Due to these points, the derived points from your code take into account the upper part as well.

Comment: Removing the black line must be done beforehand. I suppose that p2 expands slightly outside of p1 causing the thin line to remain. If this is indeed the case you can prevent it by creating a buffer around p2 when computing the difference between the two polygons: `gDifference(p1, gBuffer(p2, width = .05))`. You can tune the width argument to the minimum value such that the line disappears.